# Software For Writing Math Equations In Blogger

Tags: math, blog

I am new to blogging world. Sometimes i need to put math equations in my blog. So, Is there any software for that and also where can I download it. Also, If there will be any other advice related to it please mention.

Comment: Did you try a search? There are many hits for example: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/blogger/install.php

Answer (score 0):

MS Word has an editor of sorts. After creating the equation, use a screen capture to grab something for the web.

Math Magic (Free)
http://www.mathmagic.com/product/litewin.html

MathCast (Free)
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mathcast/

MathType ($$ Design Science)
http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/

Comment: Using image for math formulas is a bad idea. Not only it takes much more bandwidth, it'll become blurry on hidpi screens or when the user zooms in

Comment: You're right about images if you go with jpeg or gif. I've never had an issuse when using uncompressed PNG. Bandwidth was a real concern 20 years ago when ADSL lines were the thing and having T-1 line was impressive. When the average user is connecting at 56Mbps or better, I'm not going to worry about a 2-500k image file.

Answer (score 0):

[MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) sure:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "all"} } }); </script>

<p>$$ b=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i - a \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i} {n}$$</p>
```

Also you can try [AsciiMath](http://asciimath.org/).